# Python BeautifulSoup find_all() method return unnecessary element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, return

I'm having trouble with scrapping elements with the find_all() method.

I am looking for the `<li class='list-row'>.....</li>` tag but
after scrapping it returns `<li class='list-row reach-list'>` tags with different classes too.

I tried with the `select()` method too.

Here's the python code:

```
with open('index.html', 'r') as f:
     contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    main_block = conn(limit_txt,limit).find('ul', class_='list')
    for li in main_block.find_all('li',class_='list-row'):
        print(li.prettify())
```

Here's the html file:
index.html

```
<ul class="list">
 <li class="list-row">
  <h2>
   <a href="/praca/emis/O4533184" id="offer4533184">
    <span class="title">
     Senior Developer (HTML, React, VUE.js, C#, SQL)
    </span>
   </a>
  </h2>
 </li>
 <li class="list-row reach-list">
  <ul class="list">
    <span class="employer">
     IT lions consulting a.s.
    </span>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify that you only want `<li>` tags which contains `<h2>` element (for example):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''\
<ul class="list">
 <li class="list-row">
  <h2>
   <a href="/praca/emis/O4533184" id="offer4533184">
    <span class="title">
     Senior Developer (HTML, React, VUE.js, C#, SQL)
    </span>
   </a>
  </h2>
 </li>
 <li class="list-row reach-list">
  <ul class="list">
    <span class="employer">
     IT lions consulting a.s.
    </span>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

for li in soup.select('.list-row:has(h2)'):
    print(li)
```

Prints:

```
<li class="list-row">
<h2>
<a href="/praca/emis/O4533184" id="offer4533184">
<span class="title">
     Senior Developer (HTML, React, VUE.js, C#, SQL)
    </span>
</a>
</h2>
</li>
```

---

Or: To select only `<li>` with titles: `'.list-row:has(.title)'`